# How to resize a part of my clone trooper armour?

Tags: transforms, 3d-printing

I've 3D printed some clone trooper armour as you can see in my photo. The shin piece is getting a bit tight on me around the ankles, however, it is comfortable toward the knee. I want to widen the ankle end of the armour and leave the rest as it is. The shin piece is made of two parts to allow easy fitting on the leg, so I'll need to scale both parts so that they still fit together correctly.

How do I go about enlarging the lower section only?

I have done some simple designs of my own using blender. I am still very much a beginner, but want to learn how to do this.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, making 3D printed stormtrooper armor is *sick.* I wish I had some! XD

1. Select the mesh
2. Press TAB to enter edit mode
3. Go into wireframe view mode
4. Select the bottom vertices on the mesh
5. Press "O" to enter proportional edit mode
6. Press "S", then SHIFT + Z, then drag the mouse to scale the opening of the ankle on the mesh
7. Once you stop scaling, go to the black little window that popped up in the lower right and adjust the proportional size until it looks about what you like it to be

Done!

Comment: //offtopic I wish we had 3D printing back in the days when I started trooping ;) Would have saved me a lot of modifications.

Comment: Thank you! I wont have sore ankles now haha.