# How to align two objects before I reshape them

Tags: 3d-printing

Following on from my previous [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277668/how-to-resize-a-part-of-my-clone-trooper-armour).

How would I perfectly align these two objects before I stretch the lower end of this shin armour so that both parts still fit perfectly after stretching.

[image]

Comment: Honestly, there isn't a better way than just moving the mesh along the axis (G, then X, Y, or Z for the axis) until it goes where you want it.